# Object gives type of undefined when sent to a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-chrome, firefox

I'v been coming across a strange issue. I'm sure it has to do with the scope of a variable but I can't figure out why. This is being done in Google-Chrome  31.0.1650.57 and Firefox 24.0 for the following code:
first `template.js` (the following section starts on line 28 of `template.js`) is triggered by a dropdown being changed

```
    $("select[name=class]").change(function() {
        var subclassSQL = new Array();
        subclassSQL[0] = "`class`, `type`, `subclass`";
        subclassSQL[1] = "subclass";
        subclassSQL[2] = "class";
        subclassSQL[3] = $("select[name=class] option:selected").html();
        splitArr = new Array();
        splitArr[0] = split;
        splitArr[1] = "type";
        call(subclassSQL, "subClass", "div.subClass", (function(){split(); Handlebars.registerHelper("top", function(object) {return new Handlebars.SafeString("<span>Choose your " + object[0].type + ":</span>\n<select name=\"subClass\">");});Handlebars.registerHelper("bottom", function() {return new Handlebars.SafeString("</select>");});}), splitArr, false);
    });
```

then the call function in ajaxCalls.js is triggered

```
function call(SQLarray, source, container, helper, function_, run) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/ajaxHandler.php",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {info: SQLarray},
        success: function(json) {
            var template = Handlebars.templates[source],
                tempData = {base: json}
            console.log(tempData.base);
            if (helper) {helper();}
            if (function_) {
                $(container).html(template(function_[0](function_.slice(1), tempData)));
            } else {
                $(container).html(template(tempData)); }
            if (run) {update(jQuery);}
        }
    }); 
};

function split(field, tempData) {
    console.log(tempData.base);
    return tempData;
};
```

When checked in the console upon being called, the first `console.log(tempData.base);` returns an json Object as expected. but the second returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'base' of undefined ajaxCalls.js:22
split                                                        ajaxCalls.js:22
(anonymous function)                                          template.js:37
$.ajax.success                                               ajaxCalls.js:11
c                                                             jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith                                                    jquery.js:3160
k                                                             jquery.js:8235
r                                                             jquery.js:8778
```

the syntax of the call for `function_` would be:

```
split("type", tempData);
```

why is this returning an undefined?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! The problem was because of the obfuscated line triggering the `call` function.

Upon writing it out on several lines I noticed I called spilt(); within the hepler function. But I did not send any variables! simply removing `split();` solved the issue. This just goes to show. Lining out your functions is key.